# Le mot Hagiographie et la lettre H

Tags: étymologie, grec

La question concerne le mot **hagiographie** et sa famille.
Je connais l'étymologie du mot qui vient du grec :

> agios=saint + graphie

Cependant, pourquoi existe la lettre h devant a ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Le mot *agios* commence en fait par une aspiration: il n'y avait pas de lettre "h" en alphabet grec classique, mais cette aspiration est indiquée par un "esprit rude"(un espèce d'accent) sur l'alpha initial: ἅγιος. Un transcription en alphabet latin devrait donc être plutôt "hagios".

S'il n'y a pas d'aspiration, la voyelle initiale porte un autre accent dit "esprit doux". Dans ce cas, les mots dérivés ne présentent pas de "h". Par exemple, "oxygène" vient du mot ὀξύς, qui porte un esprit doux et peut donc se retranscrire en "oxus".

Les mots d'origine grecque qui ont un "h" initial viennent de mots commençant par une voyelle portant cet "esprit rude". Par exemple les mots avec la racine *homo-* viennent de ὁμός.

Comment: Je vous remercie pour votre bonne réponse. Je suis Grec et vous avez tout à fait raison par rapport les esprits. Bravo ! L'explication est totalement logique.

Comment: D'autres exemples d'esprits rudes retranscrits par un *h* : *ἅλως* → halo, *ἅρπη* → harpe, *ἁλτῆρες* → haltères, *ἁρμονία* → harmonie et *ἑϐδομάς* → (semaine) hebdomadaire...

Comment: +1 pour d'autres exemples.  Les savants du français introduisirent les emprunts au grec avec de logique !